# Envoy Lua script - how to add cookie to request_handle:httpCall from envoy_on_request

Tags: http, lua, envoyproxy

I have a route in Envoy virtual host, before the request will hit the downstream cluster (backend)  I wish to make an HTTP call to a different cluster (auth-service).
In the request to auth-service I need to pass the cookie from the original request to the auth-service.

My route config:

```
                          - match:
                            prefix: /
                            case_sensitive: false
                          route:
                            cluster: backend 
                          typed_per_filter_config:
                            envoy.filters.http.ext_authz:
                              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute
                              disabled: true
                            envoy.filters.http.lua:
                              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.LuaPerRoute
                              source_code:
                                inline_string: |
                                  function envoy_on_request(request_handle)                            
                                    local headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
                                        "auth-service",
                                        {
                                          [":method"] = "GET",
                                          [":path"] = "/",
                                          [":authority"] = "auth-service",
                                        },"",50)
                                  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. found it.

In order to access the downstream request header via `request_handle`, you will need to use the `header()` method as follow: `request_handle:headers()`.
Then you can chain `get(<header name>)`, `add(<header name>, <value>),` remove()`

So what I did, was to get the Cookie header using `request_handle:headers():get("cookie")` and pass it to the request as cookie header.

full example:

```
                          - match:
                            prefix: /
                            case_sensitive: false
                          route:
                            cluster: backend 
                          typed_per_filter_config:
                            envoy.filters.http.ext_authz:
                              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute
                              disabled: true
                            envoy.filters.http.lua:
                              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.LuaPerRoute
                              source_code:
                                inline_string: |
                                  function envoy_on_request(request_handle)                            
                                    local headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
                                        "auth-service",
                                        {
                                          [":method"] = "GET",
                                          [":path"] = "/",
                                          [":authority"] = "auth-service",
                                          ["cookie"] = request_handle:headers():get("cookie")
                                        },"",50)
                                  end
```